# How to stop the optimization in python in 30 minutes and retrieve the current solution

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using Python with Gurobi solver. I am solving a mixed integer optimization problem and it is taking a long time to solve. I want to stop the optimization after 30 minutes and get the current solution so that this solution can be used to calculate further things in my code. How do I run this optimization only for 30 minutes?

Comment: Can you post the code which is taking 30 mins?

Comment: There is a TimeLimit you can pass on to Gurobi, See the documentation,